# How can I get the value of the checkBox list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a CheckBoxList and I fill it dynamically.
I stepped through the code and it doesn't seem to hit inside of the following method, I think the value of the selected value attribute is always false.

```
<form id="form1" action="web_page.aspx">
   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
           onselectedindexchanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
   </asp:CheckBoxList>
   <br />
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="p" runat="server"></div>

protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.p.InnerHtml = "hello";
}
```

Comment: the form must `runat="server"`

Comment: also, post how you are creating the items

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you are binding on the `page_load` event.

Try to bind it on `page load` but inside `!Page.IsPostBack`

```
 if(!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
     //bind here.
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to cast the sender to a check box list then iterate over the items:

```
  Protected Sub test(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles check1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim myCb As New CheckBoxList
    myCb = Me.check1

    For Each c As ListItem In myCb.Items
        Dim isChecked, value, text As String
        isChecked = c.Selected
        If (isChecked = True) Then
            value = c.Value
            text = c.Text
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: you cannot cast the sender to a `CheckBox`, but to a `CheckBoxList`. The `Text` property of a `CheckBoxList` gets the text of the selected item with the lowest index in the list

Comment: if you want to show every selected item, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8913545/1574689) answer can help you

Comment: sorry about that.  i've edited my comment.  It shows how to iterate over the Checkbox list to get checked values.

Comment: The original question was that it is not hitting the inside of the call.  You changed the language to VB and did not address the question.

Comment: Fair enough but what language that is used to respond should be irrelevant (unless its specific to that language).  All .Net code compiles to the CLR. New developers should be savvy enough to know that most answers are syntax/language independent and it is the overall logic that is the answer.  Common tools like this: http://converter.telerik.com/ can easily convert C# to VB